# XML tag mismatch after storyboard conflict iOS

Tags: ios, xml, storyboard

```
  <button hidden="YES" opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qxz-gx-8Ik">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="275" y="5" width="30" height="33"/>
                                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qxz-gx-8Ik">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="282" y="2" width="30" height="33"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <state key="normal" title="Edit">
                                                        <color key="titleColor" red="1" green="0.59999999999999998" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                    </state>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <action selector="updateAction:" destination="akK-dA-Jb1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="UBU-1j-Tmg"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </button>
                                            </subviews>
```

I had a storyboard merge conflict and after choosing to keep the remote branch's settings, some gitmerge text got put into my storyboard's XML content such as

HEAD <<<<<<<

==========

and >>>>>>>

I removed those lines, and I'm left with an error saying :

```
"Opening and ending tag mismatch : button line 1251 and subviews"
```

line 1251 is the very first line I've posted here that starts with button hidden = "YES"

When I'm throwing my XML into formatters such as https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html, it's saying :`

```
"Unable to parse any XML input. Error on line 13: The element type "button" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</button>"."
```

How do I go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "two" buttons, that is the conflict. You need to delete the first two lines or delete the next ones (lines 3 & 4).

```
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qxz-gx-8Ik">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="282" y="2" width="30" height="33"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <state key="normal" title="Edit">
                                                        <color key="titleColor" red="1" green="0.59999999999999998" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                    </state>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <action selector="updateAction:" destination="akK-dA-Jb1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="UBU-1j-Tmg"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </button>
                                            </subviews>
```

or:

```
<button hidden="YES" opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qxz-gx-8Ik">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="275" y="5" width="30" height="33"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <state key="normal" title="Edit">
                                                        <color key="titleColor" red="1" green="0.59999999999999998" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                    </state>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <action selector="updateAction:" destination="akK-dA-Jb1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="UBU-1j-Tmg"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </button>
                                            </subviews>
```

Comment: Savior :) Thanks a bunch Kevin.